# SCons can't find cl when building TideSDK on Win8 w/ VS2010

Tags: scons, tidesdk

I am following the directions on https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/Windows7-x86-2010-Express, but when running:

`scons debug=1`

I get errors about SCons not being able to find **cl** so I added the following to SContruct:

```
if build.is_win32():
  subprocess.call(path_to_vcvars32.bat)
```

But I am still getting the error:

```
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: *** [build\win32\objs\installer\common.obj] Error 1
```

Any thoughts on why SCons can't find cl?

Answer (score 2):

calling a windows batch file will execute it in its own shell so any environment variables it might set will be set in that shell and then forgotten. They won't be propogated to the `scons` environment, and even if they were, they'd go into the wrong place.

This bit:

> Add the following to your PATH environment variable:
>   C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin

(and possibly running the batch file) need to be done before you run `scons`